# What's the difference between text encoding when using convolution neural network?

Tags: encoding, neural-network, convolution, text-classification

Suppose that we have data [a,d,c,a,b],for the one-hot encoding, that is

```
a:1,0,0,0
b:0,1,0,0
c:0,0,1,0
d:0,0,0,1,

So the [a,d,c,a,b] is 
[1,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,1,0,1,0,0,0,0,1,0,0]
```

when I input into the embedding layer.
And for another encoding types,[a,d,c,a,b] can be represent by, dim = 4,

```
[0,3,2,0,1]
```

, and then input into the embedding layer.

So what exactly difference between this two encoding types? Are there any papers that compare that both kinds of encoding? I just found the "one hot encoding in Keras" is the second types.